# Is it possible to have a variable number of string arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, variables

Is it possible to have a variable number of string arrays?

psuedo-psuedo code example:

```
cout<<"Number of family members?"<< endl;
cin>> n;

n_1[5]= {whatever}
n_2[5]= {whatever}
n_3[5]= {whatever}
n_4[5]= {whatever}
n_5[5]= {whatever}
n_n[5]= {whatever}
```

Is that at all possible?

Comment: You're limited to 1 string array, 1 global variable and 1 arithmetic operation per C++ program.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore is that totalitarian c++?

Comment: @thang: Totalitarian C++ is normally called Java. This would be draconian C++.

Comment: What is `n_...` supposed to represent? What is `{whatever}` supposed to represent?  Provide more details about what you actually want.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The "n" is supposed to represent the number of family members; the n_... is supposed to represent a string array made for each family member from 1 to n. I hope I am being clear, sorry.

Comment: @thang I am assuming that in this universe no one has a name longer than 5 characters long. :P

Comment: you don't like people with long name?

Comment: they make things confusing!

Comment: maybe you're easily confused

Comment: Also, the challenge problem my professor has given my class does not actually require names, only 1s and 0s in ASCII. My approach to the problem has led me to believe that I need to find a way to make a variable number of string arrays in which I can enter a bunch of 1s and 0s. Here is the problem if you're curious: http://venus.cs.qc.cuny.edu/~waxman/211/Challenge%20Problem%202%20-%20To%20Add%20or%20to%20Multiply.pdf

Comment: It's true, I am easily confused. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but it sounds like what you probably want is something on this general order:

```
std::cout << "Number of family members? ";
std::cin >> n;

std::vector<std::string> family(n);    

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    std::cout << "Name[" << i << "]: ";
    std::cin >> family[i];
}
```

Comment: Is that creating n character strings for the user (so he/she can put each family member into their own string? I am not familiar with std::vector syntax, I am only a beginner trying a challenge problem; sorry :(

Comment: @Chase: Yes, that's creating a vector of as many strings as the user enters (as `n`).

Comment: Thanks! Also, what does placing "std::" in front of cout and cin accomplish?

Comment: cout and cin are located in the `std` namespace. `std::cout` tells the compiler that `cout` can be found in `std`.  As an alternative, before using it you can do `using std::cout;`.

Comment: So, I wouldn't need to place it in front of cout or cin? Does using namespace std; perform the same thing?

Comment: @Chase: That, plus a whole lot more which you might not have intended. Do you know all names from `namespace std`? Then why ask for all of them?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to specify the number of these arrays of strings at runtime, you could have a `vector<string>` or a `vector<vector<string>>`, depending on what exactly you mean by "string arrays".

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it in MS Visual studio, then u can just write "using namespace std;" instead of writing "std::" everywhere. I don't know if it works in other IDEs or not, because I'm new in C++ too. Sorry for offtopic :)